# Successfully launching a shell script from Finder when the path has a space in it

Tags: terminal, finder, bash

Been trying to work this out this morning and beginning to wonder if this is even possible.

When launching a shell script through Finder, either by using the extension .command or opening .sh files in Terminal, the following command is executed:

```
Macbook-Pro:~ /Users/mulquin/Desktop/test/Path\ With\ Spaces/run.sh ; exit;
Could not open input file: /Users/mulquin/Desktop/test/Path
```

Trying it with quotes instead of escape characters yields the same result

```
Macbook-Pro:~ "/Users/mulquin/Desktop/test/Path With Spaces/run.sh" ; exit;
Could not open input file: /Users/mulquin/Desktop/test/Path
```

The users this is intended for are not tech savvy so asking them to open Terminal, browse to a directory and ./run.sh is unfortunately not an option.

I had a look at [Platypus](https://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus) but the script location will be dynamic as the users will be running it from their desktops or other location they choose.

Has Apple really not noticed this issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know much about the proper use of delimiters but the second method with double quotes certainly should work. I have used it many times and it always worked.  That being said, I have to assume you are doing something wrong but I don't see it!

Comment: what machine and what version of the system are you running?

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes only around "Path With Spaces"?

Comment: @jmh your assumption was correct, I erroneously believed the error message was from Mac OS X executing the script. The error actually came from inside my script where I forgot to enclose the command in quotes. D'Oh! Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: my pleasure. glad i could help...

Comment: You may want to answer you own question, saying just what you wrote to me.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I **was** doing something wrong.

I erroneously believed the error message was caused by Mac OS X executing the script.

The reason this error was appearing was because inside my script I was executing something *without* escaping the space. Woopsie!